# Tooltip on tray icon not working on Windows with node-webkit

Tags: node-webkit

I see that tooltips were addressed on the Win platform in the latest release (0.6.3) of node-webkit, but my issue relates specificially to the tooltip (text) attribute which can be assigned to the gui.Tray element which (on Windows platforms) should appear when the icon is hovered over in the System Tray. This does not seem to work on either Windows XP or Windows 7.  Is this a known issue?

Thank you,
Jonathan

UPDATE: I find that assigning a tooltip after creation works. It is only when a tooltip is included in the option field at the time of creation where it fails.

Comment: you may need to answer and flag it as correct answer instead of update the question :)